# Multiply arrays by arrays in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, xml, permutation

I have for example three arrays (but I can have more) with some values like this:

```
table_1 = [a,b,c]; //three elements
table_2 = [d]; //one elements
table_3 = [e,f]; //two elements
```

and I want to get that output

```
<test>
 <test_1>a</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>e</test_3>
</test>

<test>
 <test_1>a</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>f</test_3>
</test>

<test>
 <test_1>b</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>e</test_3>
</test>

<test>
 <test_1>b</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>f</test_3>
</test>

<test>
 <test_1>c</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>e</test_3>
</test>

<test>
 <test_1>c</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>f</test_3>
</test>
```

Maybe someone knows how to do this in JAVA. If I have two arrays I can do this with two for (for in for), but I have to do this more generic.

Comment: The first thought was to use recursion (but I don't know how to do this). Another thought was to use graph BSF or DSF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class MatrixCross {

    public static void cross(String[]... matrix){
        cross(0,matrix, Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
    }

    private static void cross(int index,String[][] matrix, List<String> result){
        if (index >= matrix.length){
            System.out.println("<test>");
            int i = 1;
            for (String str : result) {
                System.out.println(" <test_"+i+">"+str+"</test_"+i+">");
                i++;
            }
            System.out.println("</test>");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix[index].length; i++) {
                List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(result);
                values.add(matrix[index][i]);
                cross(index+1,matrix,values);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] table1 = {"a", "b", "c"};
        String [] table2 = {"d"};
        String [] table3 = {"e","f"};
        cross(table1,table2,table3);
    }
}
```

output:

```
<test>
 <test_1>a</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>e</test_3>
</test>
<test>
 <test_1>a</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>f</test_3>
</test>
<test>
 <test_1>b</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>e</test_3>
</test>
<test>
 <test_1>b</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>f</test_3>
</test>
<test>
 <test_1>c</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>e</test_3>
</test>
<test>
 <test_1>c</test_1>
 <test_2>d</test_2>
 <test_3>f</test_3>
</test>
```

Comment: I always know that recursive algorithms is simpler :)

Comment: Thx you a lot. I know  it should be recursion, but I didn't know how to to this.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have list of your arrays

```
List<String[]> list;
```

All you need is learn how to increment numbers in variable based system.
It not any different from constant based like base ten.
You try to increment last digit, if there is overflow you set it to 0 and try to increment next digit.

So we need representation for number. Lets make array containing digits.

```
int[] number = new int[list.size()];
```

To increment it we need a variable for current digit;

```
int current = 0;
```

and we will traverse our number until we can increment digit without overflow

```
while(true){
    if(number[current] == list.get(current).length){
        //Overflow happend
        number[current] = 0;
        current++;
    } else {
        //We can increment current digit
        number[current]++;
        break;
    }
    if(current == list.size()){
        //we out of digits
        throw new OverflowException();
    }
}
```

Now we know how to increment our number. You can do it in loop until exception happens and get all possible numbers.

Decoding number to XML is obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution I could come up with:

```
public class Test {

    public static String[][] array = {
                               {"a", "b", "c"},
                               {"d"}, 
                               {"e", "f"}
                              };


    public void recurse(String result, int i) {
        if(i >= array.length) {
            printResult(result);
            return;
        }

        for (String element : array[i]) {
            recurse(result + element, i + 1);
        }
    }

    public void printResult(String result) {
        System.out.println("<test>");

        for(int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print("  <test" + (i + 1) + ">" + result.charAt(i) + "</test" + (i + 1) + ">");
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("</test>");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.recurse("", 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your example fails with strings larger than 1 length, try with this: public static String[][] array = {{"a"},{"ds","b"}};

Comment: That's true, but the most important part (recursion) is correct. I just chose a very simple way of storing results (String). I could have chosen a Collection to make it more robust, but that's just details.